# How to disable location in nginx from bash command line?

Tags: bash, nginx

Say I have a config in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/myscript.conf`

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name _;

  location = /a {...} # <-- needs to be disabled during maintainence
  location = /b {...}
  location = /c {...} # <-- needs to be enabled during maintainence
}
```

For maintainence I need to disable `/a` location, do some commands\deployments, then enable `/a` location back.

Can this be done automatically via bash, without programmatic config modifyings?

Answer (score 4):

You can use includes and then just deal with creating and removing symlinks. Usually you see this done with server blocks (the base nginx.conf actually just includes conf.d/* which is how it loads *your* server blocks), but it can be done with anything. Basically you'll have two folders, named something like locations-available and locations-enabled, and put all of your location blocks in individual files in locations-available. In your server block include locations-enabled/* and then symlink all the locations you want enabled from locations-available to locations-enabled. Every time you add or remove symlinks just reload nginx and you should be good to go.

In you case just rm the symlink, reload, do whatever you want, recreate symlink, reload.